# Calculation of expected value given cdf

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with a distribution function.

$F(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &  0 < x  \\
      \alpha x^2  &  0 \le x < 2 \\1&x\ge2\end{cases}$

for some real $\alpha $. Then $E(X )$ is ?

since $F(X)$ is right continuous $F(2)=F(2)^-$

therefor $\alpha=\frac{1}{4}$

$E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}
[1-F(x)]dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}
(1-\frac{x^2}{4})dx=\left (x-\frac{x^3}{12}\right)_{0}^{2}=2-\frac{8}{12}=\frac{24-8}{12}=\frac{16}{12}=\frac{4}{3}$

Did I do it right? Can anyone please confirm  my answer?

Comment: No.  There are not enough information to deternine $\alpha$, unless you know $X$ is a continuous random variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot find the exact value of $\alpha$ but you can calculate the expectation, as you did

$$\int_0^2(1-F)dx=\dots =2-\frac{8}{3}\alpha$$

Where $0<\alpha \leq \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: edited tommik please check. https://prnt.sc/1003p53

Comment: @Daman Now it's correct